# "we are not holding below booking any longer "versus " we are no longer holding below booking"

Tags: grammar, difference

I always have a confusion that which one is right to use between these two sentences.
1.we are not holding below booking any longer.
2.we are no longer holding below booking.
Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  However, in each case it should be "*the* below booking", or better yet, "the booking shown below".